# How to retrieve database metadata from vert.x scala jdbc client?

Tags: jdbc, vert.x

How to get `java.sql.Connection` instance from the vert.x JDBC client from the current connection so that it can be used to retrieve the metadata of the tables/columns. Using `"io.vertx" %% "vertx-jdbc-client-scala" % "3.5.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Instances of `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection` provide the `unwrap` to access the underyling `java.sql.Connection`.

When using the Scala-wrapper you have to get the underyling connection as the ùnwrap`-method is currently not exposed (we are discussing how we can provide such methods in the future).

use asJava to get the underyling object and then invoke unwrap directly:

```
val  con:ìo.vert.scala.ext.sql.SQLConnection = ...
con.asJava.asInstanceOf[ìo.vert.ext.sql.SQLConnection].unwrap(...)
```

`

Comment: My connection is of type `io.vertx.scala.ext.sql.SQLConnection` which doesn't have `unwrap` method. Are there any docs or code samples which I can refer to?

Comment: What version are you using?
I checked the recent 3.5.1, check the code at the bottom of SQLConnection

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-sql-common/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.java

Comment: The package is different. `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection `. I have scala SQLConnection. `io.vertx.scala.ext.sql.SQLConnection`

Comment: I need the Vert.x-version you are using. The method was introduced in March 2017. It should be available in all versions 3.5.0 and higher.

Comment: Using `3.5.1`. Its available in `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection` not in `io.vertx.scala.ext.sql.SQLConnection`. When I connect to JDBCClient in scala, my connection is of type `io.vertx.scala.ext.sql.SQLConnection`.

Comment: Oh man, I am sorry, overlooked the scala-part (of which I am the actual maintainer).
unwrap is not part of the generated API so what you have to do is acces the underlying `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection`. Invoke `sqlconnection.toJava.asInstanceOf[io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection].unwrap()`.

I type this without seeing the API as I am currently not in my IDE so it might look a little different.